# Starttls: me or them?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpfox, starttls

Im running phpfox on my own server and trying to use smtp to send emails. Im setting up windows live domain emails currently waiting for domain ownership whilst waiting i tried with my normal email address something@hotmail.co.uk.

When i enter all the information i get the need to send starttls errors.

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP server error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
SMTP Error Message: SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 BLU0-SMTP126.phx.gbl Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at Mon, 13 Jan 2014 00:37:24 -0800 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-BLU0-SMTP126.phx.gbl Hello [MYIP] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 41943040 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-TLS 250-STARTTLS 250 OK 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first 
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Before i contact the support could the problem be something on the server like a module that needs downloading or activating.

And also if any one has a fix for this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're connecting to a SMTP that requires TLS/SSL (and it's letting you know that by sending `STARTTLS`), however your PHP script does not issue a `STARTTLS` back and so the target SMTP server refuses further communication. You need to enable TLS/SSL support in your PHP script.

Comment: What port did you set in the mail settings? (PhpFox uses PhpMailer internally which supports secure connections)

Comment: Maybe you're missing openSSL support in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I was putting the smtp host down as "smpt.live.com" - when in phpfox it should be written as

```
ssl://smtp.live.com
```